# @font-face attribute suddenly stopped working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I came across something rather weird - A couple of days ago, I installed 2 fonts into my website with local .woff files. Everything was alright, I tested it on a couple of devices across different browsers and OS's and it worked perfectly fine. However, this morning, when I opened the website, it was all in a generic font. I haven't changed anything at all, it just stopped working on every single browser. What could be the problem?

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bebas Neue Regular';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Bebas Neue Regular'), url('BebasNeue Regular.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('PT Sans Narrow'), url('PTN57F.woff') format('woff');
}

body {
  color: #666;
  font: 500 15px/15px PT Sans Narrow;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #eee;
  min-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font: 700 3em 'Bebas Neue Regular';
  padding: 5em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue Regular';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.75em 3em;
}

h3 {
  font: 200 1em 'Bebas Neue Regular';
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @font-face is a CSS rule statement, not an attribute.

Comment: You didn't install a font locally with that name by mistake? Otherwise, maybe just a hiccup on the server; clear your cache and try again. If that's not it, can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Or if all else fails, provide a link to the website.

Comment: @MrLister the link is http://pavdesign.net

Comment: The requested URL /assets/BebasNeue Regular.woff was not found on this server.

Comment: My url isn't going there, I tried to move the .woff files to that directory, but it's still not working. Where did you get that error from?

Comment: From the browser itself. The css is in the /assets/ directory, so I tried putting http://pavdesign.net/assets/BebasNeue%20Regular.woff into the location bar. A similar error can be found in the error console.

Comment: But the fonts are located in the root, right? That is one directory up from /assets/, where the CSS is, so the path in the CSS file should read `url('../BebasNeue Regular.woff')`

Comment: Nope, still not working. It shouldn't be in the code, it was working a couple of days ago... Thanks anyway

Comment: I somehow managed to make it work with the same code I pasted here as an example. I have no explanation.